# change my query to get the max and min values from a table column

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following function:

```
function get_max_weight()
{
   global $db;
   $query = "SELECT weight FROM products WHERE weight=(select max(weight) from products)";
   $result = mysql_query($query);
   $results = mysql_fetch_row($result);
   return $results[0];
}
```

I am using the nouislider and using `$maxweight = get_max_weight()` to define the upper limit for the slider range. I would now like to get the minimum weight from the same function.

So my questions are 1) how would I change the query above to get both the max and min values; and 2) how would I output these values on my page?

Comment: thank goodness for useful contributions like the ones below. I'm just a beginner looking for guidance.

Comment: The PHP **`mysql`** interface is deprecated. You would be doing yourself a favor if you chose to use either the **`mysqli`** or **`PDO`** interfaces.

Comment: i'm going to have to look into that spencer, thank you for your input. I have many functions and will need to get an expert to make sure everything done correctly. time to start saving !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
$query = "SELECT max(weight), min(weight) FROM products";
$execute = mysql_query($query);
$result = mysql_fetch_row($execute);
return $result;
```

And to get the vaules

```
echo $result[0]; //gives you max weight.
echo $result[1]; //gives you min weight
```

Comment: np I'm glad you found it helpful :)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a subquery, just:

```
$query = "SELECT MIN(weight) AS minweight, MAX(weight) AS maxweight FROM products";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
return $row;
```

This will return an associative array like:

```
[ 'minweight' => 10, 'maxweight' => 50 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you need a subquery, it looks like you are only fetching one row, so why would you need a query to return more than one row?

A single query can return the minimum and maximum values, for example:

```
SELECT MIN(weight) AS min_weight
     , MAX(weight) AS max_weight
  FROM products
```

As far as returning those two values from the function, I think you can return a single array object from the function.

---

The PHP **`mysql`** functions are deprecated. There are two viable interfaces available: **`mysqli`** and **`PDO`**.  (I can't in good conscience give an answer that includes calls to the deprecated `mysql_` functions.)